# Rendering database results in Jinja seems to add extra {} characters

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to render results from a SQLite database query in my template.  However, they all look like `{ColIntitule': u'I like IceCream'}`.  I don't want the `{}` or column name.  How do I render this correctly?

```
def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = g.db.execute(query, args)
    rv = [dict((cur.description[idx][0], value) for idx, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv

@app.route('/toto')
def toto():
    entries = query_db("select ColIntitule from toto where col1 = 1")
    return render_template('show_results.html', entries = entries)
```

`show_results.html`:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<ul class=entries>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><h2>{{ entry }}</h2>
    <br>
    {% else %}
    <li><em>No entry here</em>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entries` is a list of `dict` objects so when you print them in your template using `{{ entry }}`, you are printing the `dict` repr.

Your template should look more like this

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<ul class=entries>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><h2>{{ entry["ColIntitule"] }}</h2>
    <br>
    {% else %}
    <li><em>No entry here</em>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yeah! I've learnt something new today. You've got the point. One last question though, how can I remove the `.` from the html part. Sounds like a list. Is there a way to not present that as a list? Cheers.

Comment: I don't see a `.` anywhere in the code so it must be in the database? Also your `<li>` tags are not closed and `<h2>` is not a valid child element of a `<li>`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a typo in the question but, in `toto()` where is `entry` defined and set? Is there a global lurking about?

The fact that the results of the query are bound to `entries`, but `entry` is being passed to `render_template()` *might* explain this.